# git config --global alias.unstage 'reset HEAD --' meaning

Tags: git

I see the following git alias :

```
git config --global alias.unstage 'reset HEAD --'
```

what is the meaning of -- here ?

Answer (score 1):

`--` tells the command that all options are finished, and that only arguments will follow.

In this case, the arguments for `git reset` expect file names.

So it's not expecting you to provide any more options like `--soft` or `--hard` and you don't have to specify any file names, and it will reset the whole staging area, but you could just reset specific files at this point by listing the file names.